# Hikari Pool isn't utilizing max connections

Tags: postgresql

I have the Hikari `maxConnections` set to 100. However no matter how much traffic I direct at the application, active connections count does not exceed 3-4. (This includes enough stress where the requests start timing out)

[image]

(Purple = idle connections, blue = active connections)

I tried doing a thread dump but the stack trace isn't giving me anything useful for the Hikari threads

```
stackTrace:
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos()
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos()
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take()
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take()
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker()
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()
at java.lang.Thread.run()
```

However, one weird behavior I am seeing is all these threads labelled `pool-5-thread-1`, `pool-14-thread-1` etc. It was my understanding that in Hikari a connection would correspond to a thread and there would be one thread pool. It is unclear to me where these extra pools are coming from.

I would appreciate any recommendations as to how to debug this utilization problem

Comment: Well apparently all your DB requests are so fast, that you never need more database connections. That's a good thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name See the comment above regarding request timeouts "This includes enough stress where the requests start timing out)".

Comment: This seems more like a Hikari/Java question, not really a DBA question for Postgres

Comment: Where are you seeing these threads labelled "pool-5-thread-1" etc?  Maybe It is referring to a thread-pool within Java having nothing to do with your connection pool.